# kdb5_ldap_util fails with cryptic error

Tags: kerberos, openldap

Supposedly, in order to set up Kerberos, I need to run `kdb5_ldap_util`, though I'm not sure why. However, it fails with:

```
# kdb5_ldap_util -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com create -subtrees dc=example,dc=com -r EXAMPLE.COM -s -H ldapi:///
Password for "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com":
Initializing database for realm 'EXAMPLE.COM'
You will be prompted for the database Master Password.
It is important that you NOT FORGET this password.
Enter KDC database master key:
Re-enter KDC database master key to verify:
kdb5_ldap_util: Invalid syntax while creating realm 'EXAMPLE.COM'
```

I have no idea what that error means. Googling about has lead me to believe that it's a cryptic way of telling that the "kerberos schema" hasn't been "loaded" into the LDAP server yet. Checking `/etc/ldap/schema`, there isn't a `kerberos.schema` or anything equally obvious. There is, as some resources point out, a `/usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz` and `/usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.ldif.gz`. (Why are these gzipped, other than to be obtuse to use?)

`gunzip`ing those two files into `/etc/ldap/schema` and running the following:

```
# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f kerberos.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapadd: invalid format (line 5) entry: "cn=schema"
```

Line 5 is a comment.

This is the same command that I had to [run on all the other LDIF files in that directory in order to get OpenLDAP working in the first place](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1295934). Why doesn't this schema work?

The error tells me nothing about what's going wrong, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278660/extend-openldap-schema) seems to be a close match (but implies that the Kerberos schema is broken out of the box): do I need to edit it as suggested there? Some other resources seem to also suggest the LDIF needs a `cn:` entry for each part: is that needed as well/

Answer (score 1):

`krb5_ldap_util` is indeed cryptically trying to inform me that I haven't added the Kerberos schema to the LDAP server. Unfortunately, doing so is far from trivial.

The best guide I have so far is [this one from MIT](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/admin/advanced/ldapbackend.html), though it's directions are a bit off. I'm going to mostly repeat it here, but corrected for what appears to be the modern state of the world:

1. You need to extract the schema files. They're at `/usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.ldif.gz` and `/usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz`. To extract them, run:

   ```
   gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.ldif.gz > /etc/ldap/schema/kerberos.ldif
   gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz > /etc/ldap/schema/kerberos.schema
   ```
2. Now we're about at the guide's step 1, so in a directory somewhere, create a file with:

   ```
   include /etc/ldap/schema/kerberos.schema
   ```

   Save it somewhere. I'm calling mine `/tmp/ldap-kerberos/schema_convert.conf`.
3. Make a directory to hold the results, e.g.,

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/ldap-kerberos/krb5_ldif
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   slaptest -f /tmp/ldap-kerberos/schema_convert.conf -F /tmp/ldap-kerberos/krb5_ldif
   ```
5. This will output a bunch of stuff into `/tmp/ldap-kerberos/krb5_ldif`.
   Open `/tmp/ldap-kerberos/krb5_ldif/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={0}kerberos.ldif` in `$EDITOR`. As the guide suggests, replace:

   ```
   dn: cn={0}kerberos
   cn: {0}kerberos
   ```

   with

   ```
   dn: cn=kerberos,cn=schema,cn=config
   cn: kerberos
   ```

   Look at the bottom of the file for something like:

   ```
   structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
   entryUUID: ...
   creatorsName: cn=config
   createTimestamp: ...
   entryCSN: ...
   modifiersName: cn=config
   modifyTimestamp: ...
   ```

   and remove it.
6. Add it to the server:

   ```
   ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f  /tmp/ldap-kerberos/krb5_ldif/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={0}kerberos.ldif
   ```

   You should see:

   ```
   adding new entry "cn=kerberos,cn=schema,cn=config"
   ```

`krb5_ldif` should no longer complain. Also, note that Kerberos, AFAICT, must have a name with a password to bind to. It cannot do "peer authentication", which is what we're doing when we do `-Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///`: that connects over a Unix socket, and LDAP can ask the socket what our UID is, and trust us based on that. You have to create a name with a password, and use that instead. I've already done this; mine is `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`, visible in the command in the question. Kerberos will store the password to this name in a file, so just generate a long random password and set the permissions appropriately.