# Is there an alternative to OpenLDAP / Kerberos?

Tags: authentication, authorization

Are there ways to do centralized secure network-based authentication & authorization and user management that aren't OpenLDAP and Kerberos?

Frankly, Kerberos is a nightmare to configure, leaving [cryptic](https://superuser.com/questions/713904/kerberos-server-and-logs) [errors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115097/kdb5-ldap-util-fails-with-cryptic-error) that require [digging through strace](https://superuser.com/questions/713904/kerberos-server-and-logs/716497#716497) to debug. OpenLDAP isn't exactly great either, and most “[tutorials](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1295934)” consist of cryptic, unexplained commands that you should run, and a lot of the tutorial contain incorrect advice about editing the non-existent “slapd.conf” file.

I've (mostly) gotten the hang of OpenLDAP, so it isn't too much of a problem to keep, but I've been thoroughly unsuccessful in configuring Kerberos. Is there something a bit more super-user friendly out there?

Comment: What distro are you on? I'm wondering if using a more put together system such as [389 Directory Server](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Main_Page) would make it easier to deal with OpenLDAP etc.? https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/9.0/html/Deployment_Guide/index.html

Comment: @slm: Ubuntu Precise. Looking into that 389 server, thanks; the Redhat page you linked appears to be blank?

Comment: Strange loads fine for me. It's the RHEL manual for RH Directory Server 9, that's the commercial product derived from 389. The manual is pretty much identical.

Comment: have you try NIS ?  know it's old but it's really easy